# Can I lock Dojo slider so user cannot change value?

Tags: dojo

Can I lock Dojo slider ? I need disable that user can move slider.
How to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
dijit.byId("idOfMySlider").setAttribute('disabled',true);
```